# Possible error with this x86 assembly example

Tags: assembly, x86

I was reading through a practice exam for one of my classes. The architecture for the question is x86. Question:

```
Which of the following lines of pseudo C code performs the same operation as the 
assembly statement 
    lea 0xffffffff(%esi), %eax ?
```

Options:

```
a) *(esi-1) = eax
b) esi = eax + 0xffffffff
c) eax = esi - 1
d) eax = *(esi -1)
```

Because it's a "lea" operation, I feel like the answer should be (c), but apparently the answer key says (a). Is this a typo? Or do I just have a bad understanding. Thank you.

Comment: this cannot be done in C, as the `lea` instruction is moving the result into a register, not a chunk of memory.

Comment: I understand this isn't physically possible in C, but the question basically asks for sudo C code. I made the clarification edit above.

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm fairly new to assembly, trying to keep my mind sharp is all :)

Comment: That's fine lol, but any ideas?

Comment: Well I think it's not `a` or `b` since `%eax` is the destination of the instruction. Why do you think it's minus one if offset by `0xffffffff` ?

Comment: `sudo` is a linux command to grant temporarily superuser access

Answer (score 2):

Answer `c` is right.
This kind of code is often generated by compilers (and some humans :-)) to exploit the fact that `lea` is a non-destructive version of `add`, which allows up to 3 input operands and leaves the flags untouched.

Answer (score 1):

The most correct interpretation would be:

```
eax = (esi + 0xFFFFFFFF) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

Of course this can be simplified to:

```
c) eax = esi - 1;
```

Doing the reverse (converting the pseudo-C back to AT&T):

```
a) movl %eax,0xffffffff(%esi)
b) lea 0xffffffff(%eax),%esi
c) lea 0xffffffff(%esi), %eax
d) movl 0xffffffff(%esi), %eax
```